# Regex: Match any character a, specific character b and then a again

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement an algorithm on java and I need a way to match a pattern where I find any character (lets name it a) then the character 'X' and then the same character a from before. Initial thought was regex, although after some time failing to find a way to do that I am thinking of iterating through all characters and checking them one by one...

But before that if anyone could help, I need something so that ( "AXA", "EXE", "RXR", etc) would match while ("AXB", "EXA", "TXX", etc) would not.

Tried using something like ".X." but of course failed as it matched anything before and after 'X'...

Is there a way to match something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the leading char, and use a back reference:

```
(.)X\1
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/8HiK2E0uHneDAI).

Note that in java you need to use 2 slashes to make a literal slash:

```
"AXA".matches("(.)X\\1") // true
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what i needed!